# starting expo Start gives errors

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

when I run exo project with **`expo start`** gives this **error**

```
Unable to resolve "expo-updates" from "node_modules/expo-asset/build/EmbeddedAssets.js"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
```

Kindly guide me how to resolve this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try `yarn add expo-asset` or `npm i expo-asset` and you will get rid of this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you have yarn installed then use
**yarn install expo-asset**

else you have to use
**npm i expo-asset**